# split 2 long columns into multiple double columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found this formula to split a long column into multiple columns in Excel, 10 rows each:

```
=INDEX($A1:$A100,(COLUMNS($B1:B1)-1)*10+1)
```

Can it be adapted to paste `A1:B100` cell values to `C1:D10`, then `E1:F10`, and so on in Excel at once (i.e. double columns instead of single columns)?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to divide the column number by two to allow for the paired columns, so the equivalent formula would be

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$100,INT((COLUMNS($A1:A1)-1)/2)*10+ROWS(A$1:A1),MOD(COLUMNS($A1:A1)-1,2)+1)
```

copied from C2 down to V10.

[image]